# Django - How can I copy fields in same class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I will create some texts with organize that by "subjects" and "school_classes".

Initially the "school_class" name will be the same as the "subject" name.

So, when I create a text I need that field "subject" was be auto-filled with the field information of "school_class". This is to make it easier and not to err the subject as I already have the text ready and will just copy and paste it.

Like a auto copy **only when I create the texts,** because I will change the "school_class" name in the future.

Look to my models.py
I try it:

```
from django.db import models

class Texts(models.Model):
   school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   body = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

   def subject(self):
        return self.school_class

   def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

The problem is that when I change the information in "school_class", automatically change in the "subject".

Why I need this?

In the future I will modify the "school_class" name of all my texts but I want the "subject" to remain the original when it was created.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this functionality both in admin and your own views, you should use signals, as in:

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Texts(models.Model):
   school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   body = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

   def statement(self):
        return self.collection

   def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Texts)
def texts_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:
        instance.school_class = instance.subject
```

Comment: How can I copy the id field?

I try only change **subject** to **id**: instance.school_class = instance.id. --- not work.

Comment: If you need the `id`, the object should first be created in the database; so you can't use `pre_save` (that run before saving the object in the database). Try using `post_save` signal instead.

Comment: I try post_save, but this error appeared```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'```.